# CSS image appear smaller in mobile

Tags: html, css

I have this html bellow as a signature in an e-mail. For some reason when I view it on gmail on a mobile app or browser (iPhone 5) the image will appear smaller.

This how it appears on mobile.

keystroke keystroke keystroke

[image: How it appears on mobile]

```
<head>

    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,700,500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <style>

        div {

            font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;

        }

        span {

            font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
            font-weight: 500;

        }


    </style>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<div class="container" style="display:block; width:100%; font-size:small; text-align: left;">

    <br><br>
    <hr color="#DCA84A"; style ="height:1px"/><br>

    <div style="width:900px; color: #000">

            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/3cDOpZm.jpg" alt="Logo" width="159px" height="180px" align=left style="display: block; min-height: 180px; min-width: 159px; clear: both;"/>

            <b><span style="font-weight:700; font-size:larger;"><font color= "#4560AC">Admin</font></span></b><br>
                <b><span><font color= "#4560AC">Administator</font></span></b><br><br>

            <b><span><font color= "#4560AC">Office:</span></font></b><br>
            <b><span><font color= "#4560AC">Telephone:</span></font></b><br>
            <b><span><font color= "#4560AC">Mobile:</span></font></b><br>
            <b><span><font color= "#4560AC">Fax:</span></font></b><br>
            <b><span><font color= "#4560AC">Email:</span></font></b><br>
            <b><span><font color= "#4560AC">Website:</span></font></b><br><br>

            <b><span><font color= "#4560AC">Working Hours:</font></span></b><br>
            <br><br>


    </div>

    <br><br>

</div>

<div class="container" style="display:block; width:100%; font-weight: 400; font-size:smaller;">

    <hr color="#DCA84A"; style ="height:2px"/>

    <h5><font color=gray>
            The content of this e-mail (including any attachments) is strictly confidential and may be commercially sensitive. If you are not, or believe you may not be, the intended recipient, please advise the sender immediately by return e-mail, delete this e-mail and destroy any copies

    </h5>

</div>
```

Comment: You might want to read the pixel is not a pixel is not a pixel.

Comment: Why don't you follow the pixel unit?

Comment: sorry, I fixed it. It was a leftover of me trying things.